# sending a javascript symbol through django json objects does not show

Tags: javascript, django

In Django (2.2) I am trying to send a json response  like this:

`return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)`

In the `data` object there is this value

`"unit": "\u33A5"`

(cubic meters)

when I am trying to print this value on my html page using javascript, I get this exact literal instead of the cubic meters symbol.

I cannot paste javascript code because this symbol is supposed to be displayed as a y-axis label to an echarts graph, but this what I do:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: data.unit,
    nameLocation: 'middle',
},
```

If I hardcode this "\u33A5" instead of `data.unit` in the options the cubic meters symbol appears.

my question is how am I supposed to serialize or print correctly javascript symbol codes using the django JSON's response?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of DjangoJSONEncoder and set ensure_ascii to False:

```py
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class UnicodeDjangoJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['ensure_ascii'] = False
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Pass that to JSONResponse:

```py
return JsonResponse(data, encoder=UnicodeDjangoJSONEncoder, safe=False)
```

> Note (in case you didn't know): safe has nothing to do with the symbol / unicode, only that the *top level item* can be something else than a dict.

### Javascript part

I'm not sure how you receive/process your JSON, and hand it to eCharts, but JSON.parse() should already handle this encoding correctly:

```js
const jsonData = '{"type": "value", "unit": "\u33A5/d", "nameLocation": "middle"}'
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData)
document.querySelector('#y-axis').appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.unit))
```

```html
<div id="y-axis"></div>
```

If you cannot figure that out, I suggest you change the value in the database to the unicode character itself, use the above encoder to ensure it is not escaped again and pass that to eCharts.

Comment: Thank you. that was very impressive. I still get the same thing (check it out here: https://snipboard.io/mHkp71.jpg). And yes I use safe=false because I do send something else than a dict.

Comment: But what is in your data in Django? Do you have the actual symbol there or this \u encoding? If you change it in the database to m3, it should send the real symbol and then it becomes the real symbol in the JSONResponse as well.

Comment: yes, I send this "\u33A5/d" as in `data["unit"]="\u33A5/d"`  (which is actually retrieved from the database tbh)